# Strongly-Typed Configuration in .NET Core ignores JsonProperty attribute

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json.net, .net-core

I've been playing with strongly-typed configuration in .NET Core and I've found some weird behavior.

**POCO**

```
public class ModuleConfiguration
{
    [JsonProperty("menu")]
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

**Settings.json**

```
{
  "moduleConfiguration": {
    "menu": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I load the configuration:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(path);
var config = builder.Build().GetSection("moduleConfiguration").Get<T>();
```

the **MenuItems** collection is null, but if I change "menu" to "menuItems" (in settings.json), the collection is populated correctly.

Does it mean that **JsonProperty** attribute is being ignored?

Comment: Where is the attribute `JsonProperty` defined?

Answer (score 6):

That's not how `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` (and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` in particular) works. It doesn't use JSON.NET to deserialize the configuration due to the fact that configuration settings can come from different sources, for example xml files, environment variable or command line parameters.

All of these are stored in a dictionary and queried.

For example if you want to access `moduleConfiguration.menu` via configuration you have to do `Configuration["moduleConfiguration:menu"]` (note that colon `:` is used as separator for child objects).

For the reasons named above, annotating the property via `[JsonProperty("menu")]` won't do anything, because JSON.NET isn't involved in the process and the Attributes are just meta data and do not do anything by themselves.

Also when you observe the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs#L21-L32), you will see that it uses the `JsonReader` and a visitor pattern to populate the dictionary.

That being said: the property in C# and the properties in json (or xml or commandline parameters) must exactly (case insensitive).