# Newtonsoft.Json attributes not respected when using ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

The ConfigurationBuilder in Asp.Net Core 2.0 is using Json.Net/Newtonsoft.Json under the hood for the `.AddJsonFile()` functionality. I've seen it referenced in parsing errors as well as in the source for `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser`. However, it's ignoring the Attributes I'm used to decorating my properties with (e.g. `JsonProperty`).

Is there a way to get that to happen?

### Given this example.json file:

```
{
    "ExampleObjectSection": {
        "Prop": "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

### ...this class

```
class Example
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prop")]
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

### ...and this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IConfigurationRoot cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("example.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
    Example e1 = cfg.GetSection("ExampleObjectSection").Get<Example>();
    // Here: e1.Property = null

    string str = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "example.json"));
    Example e2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Example>>(str)["ExampleObjectSection"];
    // Here: e2.Property = "Hello World!"
}
```

### The result is that

The object isn't deserialized as it is when going directly through JsonConvert.

Again: Can normal Newtonsoft deserialization functionality be used? Or is there a new way to do this? (DataMember/DataContract attributes didn't seem to do anything either, but I really didn't go down that rabbit hole.)

Comment: That **question** does not, but it's **answer**---linked 3 years ago in the answer below---does.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to point to the other thread, since the answer here does not contribute anything but a link to the other answer. But your question is better to find (I just encountered the same problem), so we should definitely leave it as a signpost. This way possible future solutions for the same problem are directed to a single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer [Json - strongly - typed configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43101177/2473163) Configuration does not care about jsonproperty name.

-- **off-topic content has been removed** --

Comment: The first sentence and reference link answers the question (confirms what I found in the source code); thanks! The rest of it is off-topic.